# Blanks in the SharePoint "Top Queries by Day" search report

Tags: search, result-source

Whenever I pull a "Top Queries by Day" report from my SharePoint site, I am seeing a record with  **Query Text** blank but I don't know why and from where these blank query texts are getting logged into the search log. Is there any way I can prevent blanks in the search report?
See below screen:
[image]

**Update:**
I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise On Prem.

Comment: How is your custom result source showing up in reports? Number of queries report doesn't show result sources which I had created and performed search using it. Can you help me out ???

Answer (score 3):

Please check the  similar issue in Msdn

[SharePoint 2013 search analytics reports - 'query text' column value is empty in 'top queries by month' report](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f75ddec7-1d06-4e81-9998-82811650d8e5/sharepoint-2013-search-analytics-reports-query-text-column-value-is-empty-in-top-queries-by?forum=sharepointgeneral)

1.Run the script to start the timer job:

```
$ua = Get-SPTimerJob -Type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.UsageAnalyticsJobDefinition
$ua.GetAnalysisInfo()

$ua = get-sptimerjob -type microsoft.office.server.search.analytics.usageanalyticsjobdefinition
$ua.DisableTimerJobSchedule()
$ua.StartAnalysis()
$ua.EnableTimerJobSchedule()

$ua = Get-SPTimerJob -Identity ("job-usage-log-file-import")
$ua.RunNow()
```

2. Please install the SharePoint 2013 March update if our version is before this:
   SharePoint 2013 March update:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2767999

Comment: Thanks Tarun. Let me try this on my test as well as Prod  environments. Will update this soon.